(Wireguard Easy) How to Block internet access for all connected clients while still allowing LAN access
Hello im using a Docker container on my Ubuntu server with CasaOS installed and tried to configure the Wireguard Iptables so that connected clients via VPN can acess my LAN Services: like Jellyfin, Nextcloud, Kavita...
but that they cant acess the Internet or that they use their own network interface when using the internet.
can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance
Here is the WG Easy repo: https://github.com/wg-easy/wg-easy
Here is my current configuartion:
  - PORT=51821
  - WG_PORT=51820
  # - WG_CONFIG_PORT=92820
  # - WG_DEFAULT_ADDRESS=10.8.0.x
  - WG_DEFAULT_DNS=192.168.2.184, 1.1.1.1
  # - WG_MTU=1420
  - WG_ALLOWED_IPS=192.168.2.0/24,
  - WG_POST_UP= iptables -I FORWARD -i wg0 -d 192.168.X.0/24 -j REJECT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
  - WG_POST_DOWN= iptables -I FORWARD -D wg0 -d 192.168.X.0/24 -j REJECT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
  # - WG_PERSISTENT_KEEPALIVE=25
  # - WG_PRE_UP=echo "Pre Up" > /etc/wireguard/pre-up.txt
  # - WG_POST_UP=echo "Post Up" > /etc/wireguard/post-up.txt
  # - WG_PRE_DOWN=echo "Pre Down" > /etc/wireguard/pre-down.txt
  # - WG_POST_DOWN=echo "Post Down" > /etc/wireguard/post-down.txt
  # - UI_TRAFFIC_STATS=true
  # - UI_CHART_TYPE=0 # (0 Charts disabled, 1 # Line chart, 2 # Area chart, 3 # Bar chart)

image: ghcr.io/wg-easy/wg-easy
container_name: wg-easy
volumes:
  - etc_wireguard:/etc/wireguard
ports:
  - "51820:51820/udp"
  - "51821:51821/tcp"
restart: unless-stopped
cap_add:
  - NET_ADMIN
  - SYS_MODULE
  # - NET_RAW # ⚠️ Uncomment if using Podman
sysctls:
  - net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
  - net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1][1]


You want some simple forwarding rules like this:
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -d <yourlannetwork> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j DROP

So in your config that would mean:
  - WG_POST_UP=iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -d <yourlannetwork> -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j DROP; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
  - WG_POST_DOWN=iptables -D FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -d <yourlannetwork> -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j DROP; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

You allow what you want, then you drop everything else.
Now to be sure that users can access internet (not via the VPN) while connected, you need to be sure their profile doesn't end with:
AllowedIPs   = 0.0.0.0/0

And that you did properly configure them with:
AllowedIPs   = <yourlannetwork>


Thank you very much, it worked
